# Add view behind tableview in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, github, uiscrollview

I'm trying to add this custom control below my tableview in a TableViewController:
https://github.com/zogieosagie/RMEIdeasPullToSortControl

In the example the creator gives, the control is implemented using a ViewController and an added tableview, but I want to use it in a TableViewController. I have created and initialized it as shown in the example but I cannot get it to show up behind the table. Any ideas?

Here is a screenshot of the control above my tableview: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojfpacxelcy9cqm/Photo%20May%2028%2C%208%2057%2035%20PM.png

Here is my code in the viewDidLoad method:

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    self.rmeideasPullDownControl = [[RMEIdeasPullDownControl alloc] initWithDataSource:self delegate:self clientScrollView:self.tableView];
    self.sortTitlesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Listed from A - Z", @"Listed from Z - A", @"Brand value: HIGHEST - LOWEST", @"Brand value: LOWEST - HIGHEST", @"Founded: OLDEST - NEWEST", @"Founded: NEWEST - OLDEST", nil];


    CGRect originalFrame = self.rmeideasPullDownControl.frame;

    self.rmeideasPullDownControl.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 45.0, originalFrame.size.width, originalFrame.size.height);

    //It is recommended that the control is placed behind the client scrollView. Remember to make its background transparent.
    //[self.view insertSubview:self.rmeideasPullDownControl belowSubview:self.tableView];
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.rmeideasPullDownControl];
    [self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:self.rmeideasPullDownControl];
```

Comment: This is really hard to mentally visualize. Do you have enough reputation points to add an image describing your problem to this question?  Are the table view cells hiding the control you're trying to add behind the table?

Comment: There is no "behind" in a table view controller, because the table view is the controller's self.view.

Comment: I'm not confident I understand a tableview's internal hierarchy, except that it has cells.  It's a good guess that those are added on on the top (in the z dimension) whenever they are added or reused.  That would cause one to guess that this special subview will always be at the back if it's added before any cells.  I guess the problem you're having is evidence to the contrary.

Comment: @rdelmar Actually, there is "behind". UILayoutContainerView is.

U can make it in this way:

[self.tableView.superview addSubview:self.rmeideasPullDownControl];

Comment: As @danh mentioned, U can also play with layer.zPosition of both self.tableView and your custom control.

Comment: @DennisPashkov, I don't see that superview when I log self.tableView.superview in a tableViewController. I get the window as the superview.

Comment: @Michael Dautermann, sorry for the confusion. Basically I can get the custom control to appear on top of the table in my UITableViewController, but when I try to move it below by adding this line: [self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:self.rmeideasPullDownControl]; it disappears. I will try to upload an image.

Answer (score 1):

Table view controllers do not lend themselves to managing anything other than a table view. In a table view controller the content view of the view controller is the table view.

You should not try to add other views as subviews of a table view.

Those 2 things combined mean that you can't do what you are trying to do.

Instead, you should create a regular UIViewController. In your storyboard, add a container view to the view controller's content view. Create a UITableViewController as a separate scene, and then control-drag from the container view onto the table view controller. That will set up an embed segue, so your table view controller becomes a child view of the regular view controller. Now you can do whatever you want to the main view controller's content view, including adding other views behind the table view.

Comment: Would I be able to add an IBOutlet of the tableview in the container to my UIView subclass? I have to connect the custom control to a scroll view (table view), so I can't just add it to the view without connecting it to what's inside the container.

Comment: @user258268 First: You mean UIViewController subclass, Second: You cannot directly link it with an IBOutlet, but you can give the embed segue in the storyBoard an identifier and then in -prepareForSegue in your UIViewController subclass you wait for this segue to fire. From there you can get the tableViewController from segue.destinationViewController. Then you can get the tableView from the tableViewController and save a link in a property of your viewController.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you are using a Table View Controller on the storyboard?  Or do you mean that your backing code is a subclass of UITableViewController?

I haven't used this project before but I'm guessing you are using a Table View Controller on the storyboard, in which case there is no backing view for the RMEIdeasPulldownControl to attach to (the top-level view is a UITableViewController). If you look in the example it needs to be attached to a scrollview (like a table view) but it needs to be inserted into a view (like a UIView)

If you meant the second one then I'm not sure, UITableViewControllers are subclassed from UIViewControllers and are really very similar, so I can't imagine any trouble arising from that.

Comment: Yes, I have a UITableViewController on the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible directly, but you can create `UIViewControllerClass` with relevant storyboard `UIViewController`

- add a `MyUIView` in hierarchy then `UITableView` next to `MyUIView`
- attach datasource and delegates for `UITableView` and use `MyUIView` as per your requirement.